# Chrome Extension background view invalid

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, I load unpackage extension, the Extension Manager show the infomation `background.html (invalid)` ， and the extension is not working， such as the below picture:

(ps: I use the Chrome of Chinese Version, so I don't know what is the information in English Version)

[image: question detail]

when I refresh the extension, the extension is available, and a few seconds later, it's not working...go round and begin again, please help.

Comment: You should boot Chrome in english, see what's the error and then put it back in chinese.

Comment: Is it possible that this means "inactive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`（无效）` is `(inactive)` in the English version of Chrome. It means that your background.html is declared as an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), which will be closed when Chrome detects that it has been idle for a while.

If your extension does not work under these conditions, then edit your `manifest.json` file and change `"persistent": false` to `"persistent": true` to make turn it into a persistent [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

Comment: Oh... I just know the literal meaning, thanks a lot for your help